Non-permissible value for Friedmann Equation?
Consider the Friedmann Equation describing a Universe without cosmological constant $\Lambda$:
$$\left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\right)^2 = \frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho-\frac{kc^2}{a^2}$$
On the left hand side, there is a square around Hubble parameter, which will produce a positive number, and density $\rho$ is obviously a positive number, then it will create some non-permissible values for both $\rho$ and $k$ (i.e. $\frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho-\frac{kc^2}{a^2}$ is greater than $0$).
Does that imply some universe cannot exist because it contradicts this equation? How would we interpret these non-permissible values? Is there some other ways to get around it?
